# Express Session and Amazon Beanstalk with health check

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, mongoose, express-session, connect-mongo

I have a problem with express session, connect-mongo and Amazon Beanstalk.

Each time that Amazon Beanstalk wants to check health, It's doing a request to API but it creates a new document in mongodb database.
So, in a short time Amazon creates 200.000 new documents with session that doesn't serve.

Is there way that I can ignore thats requests?

Thanks.

Comment: I would look at the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921658/use-specific-middleware-in-express-for-all-paths-except-a-specific-one In general I think you will want to setup a health-check endpoint that doesn't invoke the session creation middleware.

Comment: Thanks! You put me in the right direction. I found this answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22882673/1741027 ... I believe that it is the answer for my problem.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what you need, glad I could help and sorry I couldn't come up with the full answer directly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this EXACT same problem, and just posted a solution here in case anyone is still having the same problem. Hope this helps!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47850419/1791845